# ios regex mention until special character + avoid space

Tags: swift, regex

i have string like below

> @a b@mail.com has joined

i want to show @a b c as mention, but hard to detect space, so i put the string like below before using regex

```
 @``a b@mail.com`` has joined
```

So i want to detect start with

```
@``
```

and end with

```
 ``
```

can anyone help me the regex, i tried so much but still not working, here is the regex im testing

```
^@``.*``{3,}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a capture group and capture any char except an @ using a negated character class.

```
^@``([^@\r\n]+).*?``
```

The pattern matches

- ``` ^@`` ``` Start of string, match @ and 2 backticks
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^@\r\n]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except @ or a newline
- `)` Close group 1
- ``` .*?`` ``` Match as least as possible chars until 2 backticks

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pxV2ZV/1/)